# Move onboarding logic into hook/context

Tags: react-native, hook

I have an onboarding process that requires the user to click a button to acknowledge or dismiss the screens and make it to the regular app.

Currently I have the logic laid out like this, split between my Nav and Onboarding components.

**Nav**

```
const [onBoarded, setOnBoarded] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const isOnBoarded = async () => {
            const ob = await EncryptedStorage.getItem('ONBOARDED');
            setOnBoarded(!!ob);
        }
        isOnBoarded();
    }, []);

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="onboarding"
        >
            {!onBoarded && <Screen name="onboarding" component={Onboarding} />}
            <Screen name="MainApp" component={MainApp} />
            ...
```

**Onboarding**

```
    const handleOnBoarding = () => {
        EncryptedStorage.setItem('ONBOARDED', 'true');
        navigation.navigate('MainTabNavigator');
    }

   return (
      ...
      <Button onPress={handleOnBoarding}>skip</Button>
      ...
   );
```

My question is... Is it possible to move this into a hook and keep the same functionality?

I thought it may be possible to do something like

```
const useOnBoarding = () => {
  const [onBoarded, setOnBoarded] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const isOnBoarded = async () => {
      const ob = await EncryptedStorage.getItem('ONBOARDED');
      setOnBoarded(!!ob);
    }
    isOnBoarded();
  }, []);

  const handleOnBoarding = () => {
    EncryptedStorage.setItem('ONBOARDED', 'true');
    setOnBoarded(true);
  }

  return {onBoarded, handleOnBoarding};
}

export default useOnBoarding;
```

But I can't seem to get it working?

---

**Nav**

```
const {onBoarded} = useOnBoarding();

    return (
        <Stack.Navigator
            initialRouteName="onboarding"
        >
            {!onBoarded && <Screen name="onboarding" component={Onboarding} />}
            <Screen name="MainApp" component={MainApp} />
            ...
```

**Onboarding**

```
 const {handleOnBoarding} = useOnBoarding();

   return (
      ...
      <Button onPress={handleOnBoarding}>skip</Button>
      ...
   );
```

---

At Abe's request, I put logs in:

- Between `const ob` and `setOnBoarded` to see what was being fetched and when, and also a log just to check that the `handleOB` was being hit
- In the `Nav` to see what was being brought into the component.

**Findings:**

- Fresh device - initial load:

```
useOnBoarding > useEffect
useOnBoarding > useEffect > isOnBoarded {"ob": undefined}
```

We get the onboarding screens as we would expect.

- Fresh device - Dismissing onboarding

```
useOnBoarding > handleOnBoarding
```

The onboarding screens **do not** go away - I remain on the onboarding screens.

- Fresh device - close app, clear from running apps and reload

```
useOnBoarding > useEffect
useOnBoarding > useEffect > isOnBoarded {"ob": "true"}
```

It skips the onboarding process!

**Added onBoarded: {onBoarded}** to the top of the onboarding screens return as to check if the `useState` is being set at the time of clicking the skip button.

I can see that the `{onBoarded}` does change from `false` to `true` on the onboarding screens, so clearly it's not doing something within the Nav... Maybe something else is to blame.

I went back to the Nav and added

```
useEffect(() => {
  console.log('AppNavigator > useEffect > onBoarded changed state', {onBoarded});
}, [onBoarded]);
```

to check whether the triggering of the `handleOB` in the onboarding component would change the `onboarded` in here... **it did not** and now I think about it, of course it didn't... They're two separate instances of the same hook. **This isn't context.**

Maybe I shall try context instead. Or stick with how I had it.

Comment: can you say more about what's not working?

Comment: @Abe the app doesn't remember that it has been set as onboarded after you close it down, remove from running apps and start it back up... I thought the EncryptedStorage set and get would mean that it would remain in storage... I have added more to the Q regarding how I have tried using the new hook to hopefully give more explanation

Comment: Thanks, have you tried adding some logs? What gets retrieved from encrypted storage, is the function definitely getting called, etc

Comment: @Abe - See my updated Q... I think the way it's looking is that I should try using a context instead... But I have tried that before without success also due to the async nature of things?

Comment: @Abe - OMG I've sussed it! Thanks for being my sounding board :-P The penny dropped after explaining the logs showing that it was 2 instances of the hook causing things to not work and that it should be done via context that I had already attempted to use, but hadn't managed to get working last week. So I've redone it, actually thinking about it this time and it works! Boom. I will post an answer myself to document the fix. - I did it all long-winded initially, and then managed to refactor to work my actual hook into it, so I've not wasted my time completely!

Answer (score 0):

So after a bit of back and forth with @Abe and explaining the issue to them, I figured it out in my head that the issue with what I was trying was that the Nav and the Onboarding were creating their own instances of the hook that didn't know about one another - Naturally, this is how they work, but my Friday brain clearly wasn't working.

With that in mind I had to go the context route, something that I had tried previously in the week but hadn't managed to get working. However, now with my hook in place, it was actually quite simple to get it working in the end!

**context**

```
export const OBContext = createContext({}); 

export const OBProvider = ({children}) => {
  const {onBoarded, handleOB} = useOB();

  return (
    <OBContext.Provider value={{onBoarded, handleOB}}>
      {children}
    </OnBoardingContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

**nav**
Replace the current logic with:

```
const {onBoarded} = useContext(OBContext);
```

**onboarding**
Replace the current logic with

```
const {handleOnBoarding} = useContext(OBContext);
```

And it all works! Happy days